# Dynamic JqGrid MVC3 (Razor) Delete functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I am using https://github.com/robinvanderknaap/MvcJqGrid in my projet, I want to implement delete functionality with each row in Grid. I followed http://playground.webpirates.nl/mvcjqgrid sample project. I did not find any help related to delete functionality.

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

MvcJqGrid has not implemented the edit and delete functionalities from jqgrid.